Coarsened exact matching (CEM) on longitudinal data
I  want to compare the effect of 2 educational programs across time. In other words, I have tested 2 groups of students at 3 different time points (T1, T2 and T3). I have performed CEM on the data of T1, so that the 2 groups are as closely matched as possible on 3 covariates at the onset of the programs. This way, I can clearly assess the impact of the programs without the confounding influence of these covariates.   Now, I want to assess the difference in performance of these matched groups at T2 and T3. This is where I am running into some issues.

Is it correct that the estimand here concerns the ATT & a conditional effect (because matching was done in strata)?

If I want to calculate an effect size to compare the difference in group performance (say, a cohen’s d), is it correct that this should be weighted? So, for example, when comparing group performance at T1, T2 or T3, should I use the weights from the matching at T1?

I want to perform a regression analysis at T3, including some other confounding covariates that were not included in the matching procedure (so that the sample would not become too small after matching). Because this is a hierarchical, longitudinal dataset, I generally perform linear mixed modelling (LMM), with a random intercept for subject and school. Is this ok? Do the weights at T1 need to be included in the LMM as well?


